# Symfony web profiler error en entorno dev

Tags: php, apache, symfony, xdebug

tengo estos formularios

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use AppBundle\Form\CursoMatriculaType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use AppBundle\Repository\CursoMatriculaRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\CursoMatricula;

class PackMatriculaType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('packcursos',
                    CollectionType::class,
                    array (
                        'label' => 'Cursos del pack',
                        'entry_type' => CursoMatriculaType::class,
                        'allow_delete' => true,
                        'allow_add' => true,
                        'by_reference' => true,
                        'entry_options' => 
                            array(
                                'label'=> false
                            )
                    )
            );

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PackMatricula'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_packmatricula';
    }

}
```

y

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use AppBundle\Repository\CursoMatriculaRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\CursoMatricula;

class CursoMatriculaType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nombre')
                ->add('modalidad')
                ->add('tipo');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\CursoMatricula'
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_cursomatricula';
    }

}
```

Y resulta que al hacer el render con el bundle de Easyadmin así:

```
- { property: 'packs', label: 'Packs', type: 'collection', type_options: { entry_type: 'AppBundle\Form\PackMatriculaType', by_reference: false, allow_delete: true , allow_add: true, entry_options: {label: false}} }
```

Me funciona correctamente en entorno proc, pero no se porque me desaparece el web profiler cuando estoy en entorno dev.

Me desaparece el token dandome un error 404. Y me sale un conexion reset que veo dando al F12 del explorador. ALguna idea de porque puede ser. Tiene que ver algo con el X-debug??

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que al final va a ser por tirar sobre **WAMP**.

Este problema ocurre a menudo en **Windows** debido al tamaño de pila predeterminado de Apache más pequeño. Y generalmente ocurre cuando se trabaja con código PHP que asigna muchas pilas.

Para resolver este problema, agregue lo siguiente al final del archivo de configuración de **Apache**, httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

Y reiniciar **Apache**.